# show related tasks in DispForm of an item with Start Feedback Process workflow

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, designer

I have a list "**My List**" that has a "**Start Feedback Process**" workflow. The workflow creates multiple tasks in "**Workflow Tasks**".

I want to modify the `DispForm.aspx` page of "**My List**" to show all the tasks created for it through the "**Start Feedback Process**" workflow.

If I go to the `AllItems.aspx` page for "**Workflow Tasks**" I can see all the tasks there. And there is a column called `Related Content` that has a link to the associated list item in "**My List**"

But I cannot figure out how to find all the tasks created for an item in "**My List**" by the item's ID.

I thought I could add a field to "**Workflow Tasks**" to store the ID from "**My List**" by modifying the "**Start Feedback Process**" workflow but the "**Change the behavior of a single task**" sub-workflow in the "**Start Feedback Process**" workflow does not let me update values in the current task.

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by "workflow does not let me update values in the current task"? Do you mean the current item is referring  "My List" not the task?

Comment: @AhmedMahmoud Yes. I can't get to "current task item".